# zonal or template ocr invoices reading

Tags: neural-networks, topology, optical-character-recognition

I'd like to explore the possibilities of applying artificial intelligence to ocr reading.
Basic ocr invoices processing let me convert 30% of them only. 
The main purpose is defining invoices areas by training an ai, then process those areas with ocr.
So I am looking into ai to define and recognize a document topology first, then apply ocr locally.
From a brief search, it is classified as zonal or template ocr.
Any chance of a premade open source library?